# Windows authentication for ksoap services

Tags: android, ksoap2

i am using .net web services in my application, recently they added windows authentication for these web services, how to access authenticated web services from android,
please help me.

Comment: Hi @Mohan I'm developing a new service to do NTLM authentication https://www.nafiux.com/wasp/ if I can help you please let me know

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/index.html) you can use the following to register your NTLM authentication:

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
NTCredentials credentials = new NTCredentials(USERNAME, PASSWORD, WORKSTATION, DOMAIN);

client.getAuthSchemes().register("ntlm", new NTLMSchemeFactory());
client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(HOST, PORT), credentials);
```

HOST should be the address of your server.
PORT should be the port of your server, can be -1 for any port.

WORKSTATION and DOMAIN for the NTCredentials can stay empty if you don't need them.